# Required String parameter is not present : communicate with fetch

Tags: javascript, spring, fetch

I am trying to use fetch API to remove JQuery from my code and I have an issue sending the data to the server :

Here is my function :

```
url = '/authentication'
fetch(url, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
     body: {username: username}
});
```

And Spring-side :

```
@PostMapping("/authentication", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String authentication(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(name = "username") String username){
...
}
```

but I got the following error :

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'username' is not present]

What is the proper way to send data with fetch, and what am I doing wrong ? 
I tried to put `JSON.stringify` or with `{"username":username}` but it doesn't change anything.

Thanks for your help

EDIT 06/24 : I resolved it with `url = '/authentication?username='+username`, but I have issues with a long `jsonResponse` with a lots of characters... (`Request header is too large`, only on my phone)

Comment: Did you try to print the username variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RequestParam will parse the var in url.

url = '/authentication?username=abc'

if you want deal with postbody

```
public String authentication(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody YourRequest request)
```

YourRequest.java

```
@Data
public class YourRequest {


    private String username;
}
```